# Python code readablity for boolean variable driven code

Tags: python

I have a config.py file which as a bunch of bool parameters like

```
show_timer = True
display_graph = True
```

My main code runs in a while loop, and the loop seems very cluttered with code that is not executed if the above parameters are False. What is the best approach for readability for this kind of configuration file driven codes? I am currently using a format like:

```
    init_someting() if display_graph else None
    while True:
        do_something() if show_timer else None
           .
           .
           .
```

Comment: Using a conditional expression is not the way to go here, no. Just use `if display_graph: init_something()`.

Comment: speaking as more of a C#/Java programmer I would aim to eliminate all similar kinds of conditionals via polymorphism https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Comment: If you dislike the two lines for `if ...: <code>`, you could make a helper function like `do_if(condition, function_to_execute, *parameters)`, but this will only work for a single function. Personally, I would just go with the regular `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) said in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348336/python-code-readablity-for-boolean-variable-driven-code/32348970#comment52570236_32348336), don't use a conditional expression; use a normal `if` statement. It seems like you've got all the actions in functions already, so I don't think there's much else to do.

```
if display_graph:
    init_something()

while True:
    if show_timer:
        do_something()

    if other_option:
        do_other_thing()
```

**For Educational Purposes Only** *(but there are places where this pattern is useful)*

Depending on the details of what you're doing, you could also use the config options to build a list of functions to be called, then loop repeatedly over that. Something like this:

```
if display_graph:
    init_something()

functions_to_call = []

if show_timer:
    functions_to_call.append(do_something)

if other_option:
    functions_to_call.append(do_other_thing)

while True:
    for function in functions_to_call:
        function()
```

Or:

```
if display_graph:
    init_something()

all_functions = [
    (show_timer, do_something),
    (other_option, do_other_thing),
]

functions_to_call = [function for (flag, function) in all_functions if flag]

while True:
    for function in functions_to_call:
        function()
```

**/For Educational Purposes Only**

Comment: Sticking with the regual if statement seems like the simplest choice for now, but I liked the functions_to_call list idea, it will be helpful in the future. Could you tell me why should I avoid the one-line conditional expression? I kinda liked it because of it being a single line.

Comment: @ovunctuzel, it's intended to be used for returning a value, not for conditionally calling a function; you should use the normal `if` statement for that. One-liners can be cool, but that doesn't mean you should use them everywhere you possibly can. Lines are cheap :).

Answer (score 0):

If keeping additional objects is not a constraint, you can have a `dict` with config to function mapping.

```
func_dict = {'show_timer': timer_func,
        'display_graph': display_graph_func}
```

Now iterate over func_dict to check config values. Something like:-

```
for config_param, func_obj in func_dict.items():
    if config[config_param]:
        func_obj()
```

or in shorthand:-

```
[func_obj() for config_param, func_obj in func_dict.items() if config[config_param]
```

But again passing parameters to functions will be an issue. Check if you can work out on it.

Comment: Seems like a case of `Simple is better than complex` though.